# mysql: slightest difference between days

Tags: mysql, date, difference, days

i want to write a query which shows me the slightest difference between a given day of a month and the days in the tables.

```
select * from students where 5 = month(birthdate)
```

I want to search for the students who were born in May and now i want to get the slightest difference between a given day and the day of the birthday.

For example:

Alan 1980-05-03
Bob  1978-05-07

And i set the day to 8. The result should show me Bob. How should the query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE month(birthdate) = 5
ORDER BY ABS(DAY(NOW()) - DAY(birthdate))
LIMIT 1;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcbe78/5/0)**</kbd>

When you compare only in one month range you could easily get difference between day in particular month.

Note: This won't handle ties.

Answer (score 0):

Here you set the day, you choose all students with birthday that matches the birth date closest to the day you chose.

```
Set @Day = 5; -- your number
Select * from students 
where month (birthdate)=5 -- set this to month
Having birthdate = (select min(birthdate) from students order by abs(@Day - dayofmonth(birth date)) desc limit 1);
```

Dayofmonth() returns the day (1-31) of the month for a given date.